# How to pass a parameter into a SQL stored procedure?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using an MVC framework.

In my view, I have a dropdown menu that is populated with a variety of options and based on the selection from that dropdown menu I want to be able to retrieve relevant data from the database. Currently, the selected value is stored in a variable called optionSelected.

The data is retrieved through a SQL stored procedure, which is as follows:

```
CREATE PROC [Production].[p_optionData]

AS

SELECT TOP 125 **optionSelected
FROM [Production].[gen_raw_mod]
WHERE [GPN] = '1234' AND [TIMESTAMP] >= '2017-01-12 00:00:00' AND [TIMESTAMP] <= '2017-01-18 23:59:59'
ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP] ASC

GO
```

So, I was wondering if there was a way to use the value of the selected option to set a parameter in the stored procedure? I have looked into it but I'm having no luck.

Thanks in advance for any advice, I'm relatively new to this.

Comment: You can definitely use the selected value, but can you add the code you use to fetch the data so we can tell you what to change

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you need help with how to pass the value in a parameter in SQL, or in your (presumably) javascript code?

Comment: My advice is that learning to google will be your most valuable skill as a new programmer.

Comment: I have included my stored procedure above. I'm not sure how to pass the value stored in optionSelected into the SQL stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure

It gives an example of how to write the stored procedure using variables that can be passed in. In your code, it would be something like:

```
CREATE PROC [Production].[p_optionData]

    @intGPN             INT         ,
    @dteTimeStampStart  DATETIME    ,
    @dteTimeStampEnd    DATETIME;

AS

SELECT [Add required columns here]
FROM [Production].[gen_raw_mod]
WHERE [GPN] = @intGPN AND [TIMESTAMP] >= @dteTimeStampStart AND [TIMESTAMP] <= @dteTimeStampEnd
ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP] ASC

GO
```

Ensure you use the correct DATETIME data type for your needs.

Edit: Having read your questions again, if you are asking how to have a dynamic select:

```
CREATE PROC [Production].[p_optionData]

    @strOptionSelected NVARCHAR(100)

AS

    DECLARE @strSQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @strSQLQuery = 'SELECT TOP 125 '+ @strOptionSelected + ' FROM [Production].[gen_raw_mod] WHERE [GPN] = ''''1234'''' AND [TIMESTAMP] >= ''''somedate'''' AND [TIMESTAMP] <= ''''somedate'''' ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP] ASC;';

    sp_executesql @strSQLQuery;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. After some research, a dynamic select is what I'm after. I understand how to declare the parameters but I don't understand how I'll be able to have the parameter reference the optionSelected variable in the JavaScript file? Do you have any advice? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Afraid I have never worked with JavaScript in that sort of way. Post the code you have so far and I am sure someone will be able to assist.